# Variables being evaluated twice in XSLT template and Velocity

Tags: xml, xslt, velocity, apache-fop

I have a xslt template that creates a FOP file that, afterwards, I want to evaluate with velocity. When I have something like this:

```
<fo:basic-link internal-destination="${variableOutside}">
      ${variableInside}
</fo:basic-link>
```

Both variables "variableInside" and "variableOutside" are supposed to be evaluated by velocity and NOT by XSLT.

However, after the first XSLT transformation, what I get is:

```
<fo:basic-link internal-destination="$">
      ${variableInside}
</fo:basic-link>
```

That is, the variableInside has already been evaluated because XSLT assumes this is not a literal string but a variable and, since it doesn't have any value for it, it leaves it blank.

VariableOutside is, however, left unused because it is not in an attribute I guess.

Now, I know I can get rid of the curly braces and that will work, but sometimes, I need to only convert one part of the text, so, for example:

```
${variableOutside}.field1
```

Should become

```
valueofvariable.field1
```

And if I don't use the curly braces, Velocity will assume that I am looking for the field1 inside variableOutside which doesn't exist.

So, my question is, how do I escape the curly braces? I have tried with both "/" and "\" (double and single) and also with { and } but none of them work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to literally output curly braces in an attribute, rather than have XSLT treat them as Attribute Value Templates, use double braces

```
<fo:basic-link internal-destination="${{variableOutside}}">
```